# GraphicsMagick - position item in bottom left

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, command-line-arguments, graphicsmagick

After trying every combination of commands that I could possibly think of I still can't get this to work.

I have a large image that can vary in size: Logo.png
I have a small image of a 'known' size: Wallpaper.png

I want Logo to appear in the Bottom Left of Wallpaper.

This has to be done using the 'gm convert' command using -flatten. Using 'gm composite' would require me to run two commands which isn't acceptable as it would add too much time to our processing per image.

Here is the command so far (there will be more added to this command but here is the core of it):

```
wallpaper.png -page +0+0 -gravity SouthWest logo.png -compose over -flatten result.jpg
```

This puts the logo in the top left. Gravity appears to be ignored. Using +100% for -page does not work either.

Comment: I do not understand why running `gm composite` would require you to run two commands. Also, you *assume* that running two commands to 'cost more processing time' -- which is not automatically so just because `2 > 1`. To be sure you'd have to *measure* it, and take the decision based on the *facts*, not your assumptions. Lastly, your given 'command' *"wallpaper.png"* isn't really a command. You probably missed to add the real command verb. So which one is it you did use?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see the need for your use of `-flatten` and `+page`

The following ImageMagick command should work:

```
convert              \
  -composite         \
  -geometry +10+20   \
  -gravity southwest \
   background.png    \
   logo.png          \
   result.png
```

For GraphicsMagick this needs to change to:

```
gm                   \
   composite         \
  -geometry +10+20   \
  -gravity southwest \
   logo.png          \
   background.png    \
   result.png
```

I added `+10+20` to demonstrate how you can *offset* the overlaid logo a little bit from the extreme lower left corner.